# C code in Dev-Cpp breaks in runtime

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a C code like below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct __student{
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    int age;
};

typedef struct __student student;

void getStudent(student* stud)
{
    printf("Name: "); scanf("%s",stud->name);
    printf("Surname: "); scanf("%s",stud->surname);
    printf("Age: "); scanf("%d",stud->age);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    student* s = (student*)malloc(sizeof(student));
    getStudent(&s);

    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles without any error or warning in Dev Cpp 5.10.
But When I try to run this application it breaks after i entered age value.
I don't understand what is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're passing a `student**`(that is a pointer to a pointer) where your function is expecting a `student*`, also it does give a warning(at least on GCC 4.9.2)

Change your code to

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    student* s = malloc(sizeof(student)); //also don't cast the malloc
    getStudent(s);
    free(s); //we don't want memory leaks
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to passing the correct `student` as said in the answer above,

```
printf("Age: "); scanf("%s=d",stud->age);
```

should be

```
printf("Age: "); scanf("%d", &stud->age);
```

As you are typing a number that is being assigned to an `int`.

Answer (score -1):

I might have misunderstood, but there's no errors in your code. It's OK that your program exits as it reaches `return 0;` in `main` right after you enter the age.

Here the function returns right after you enter the age

```
void getStudent(student* stud)
{
printf("Name: "); scanf("%s",stud->name);
printf("Surname: "); scanf("%s",stud->surname);
printf("Age: "); scanf("%s=d",stud->age);
}
```

Here you're calling `getStudent` and then returning 0

```
student* s = (student*)malloc(sizeof(student));
getStudent(&s); // that's incorrect!!
free(s); //remove this if you're using s after this call

return 0;
}
```

**Oh yes! Didn't get this earlier, I'm sorry!** You have to use `getStudent(s);` instead of `getStudent(&s);`

Comment: Yes there is errors in his code. Your answer is wrong.

Comment: @self, I'm sorry, didn't see this.